# Uniqueness of the abelian group structure on the hom-sets of an additive category.

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

I tried to prove that the abelian group structure of the hom-sets on an additive category is uniquely defined. My proof was the following: (theorem 21.1.9 is simply the fact that a preadditive category has biproducts)

[image]

Since my proof is somewhat simpler than the one in Handbook of Categorical Algebra 2, by F. Borceux, I wonder if I didn't blunder somewhere. I'm pretty sure it is correct, but I would like to be sure. (Since this isn't really a comparison, I won't post a picture of the proof in the book mentioned. But I can do it if anyone wants.)

Comment: My first guess about the explanation is that you prove that the group structure is unique, perhaps Borceux is also concerned to prove that it exists in the presence of biproducts?

Comment: @KevinArlin he indeed does it but I'm comparing my proof to just the uniqueness part: this is proposition 1.2.7 there, which reads "On a category C, any two additive structures are necessarily isomorphic".